# forEach loop returning the value but my react useState value only returning one array obj

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, use-state

```js
const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
const [allPost, setAllPost] = useState([]);

const getAllPost = async () => {
  const q = query(collection(db, "posts", "post", user.user.email));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data());
    const newPost = doc.data();
    setAllPost([...allPost, newPost]);
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  getAllPost();
}, []);
```

I have four documents in my firestore but setState only returning one although using forEach loop i can see all four object

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that each time you use

```js
setAllPost([...allPost, newPost]);
```

`allPost` is still the previous value because [state value updates are asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069332/283366); `allPost` won't contain the new value until the next render.

You can either use the [functional version](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) of the state setter...

```js
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  setAllPost((prev) => [...prev, doc.data()]);
});
```

or simply build up a separate array and set them all at once

```js
setAllPost(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
```

Personally, I'd prefer the latter.